# Chrome ExtensionInstallSources

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

To add custom extension now we have to do this:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources

But I could not figure out how to add this in my registry?
Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallSources\1 = "https://corp.mycompany.com/*"

Is it in hkey_local_machine or hkey_current_user?

Is "1" a key or REG_SZ?

Is "https://corp.mycompany.com/*" a REG_SZ value name or a REG_SZ value data or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it in hkey_local_machine or hkey_current_user?

either way

> Is "1" a key or REG_SZ?

a REG_SZ value name, not a key.

> Is "https://corp.mycompany.com/*" a REG_SZ value name or a REG_SZ value data or something 
>   else?

a value data

the changes will apply when the browser **restarted**.